# No resource find in appcompact-v7 lib project

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have updated the my android SDK to android 5.0 with android support lib version to 21
when I try to add support v7 lib to my project it's showing following error in the appcompact-v7 lib project. before updating the Android SDK it's works fine.

```
 appcompat_v7/res/values-large-v14/themes_base.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.

 appcompat_v7/res/values-large-v14/themes_base.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
```

Can anyone help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a bug in the 5.0 appcompat_v7 library. Rolling back to the preview release fixed the problem for me. Hopefully they will release an update/fix soon.

Comment: I have commented those two themes in style.xml in value-large-v14 file support lib works for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my *copy* of v7-appcompat - I could not build it with the same errors.

What worked for me is completely removing the /res directory and copying it back from SDK. It seems that  there were some old unused styles left.

Comment: This is the only thing that solved it for me, I did it using `rsync -axv --delete /opt/android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/ libs/appcompat/`